# Sparql where clause

Tags: rdf, sparql, triplestore, fuseki

i'm trying to create a sparql query that returns every column where the column "subject" is "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator".

In sql, it should be something like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE Subject = "<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>"
```

The sparql query that comes close to what I want looks like this:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE { 
    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator> ?object ?predicate optional {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
  }
}
```

It returns a table, with all the three columns, but the ?subject column is empty for some reason. The ?predicate and the ?object column are not empty and show the correct data.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Actually, http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator is supposed to be a property, so do you really want to get all triples about this property? Do you know the base concept of triples in RDF knowledge bases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your Triplestore is populated with the correct statements then try -

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE { 
    VALUES ?subject { <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator> }
    ?subject ?predicate ?object .
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked like a charm :D Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to do this. Apart from the solution given by Anthony, with a `VALUES` clause, you can also use a `FILTER` condition:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE { 
    ?subject ?predicate ?object .
    FILTER(?subject = <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>)
}
```

or if your goal is not necessarily to get a table with three columns, but to get back all triples with that particular subject, you can also use a CONSTRUCT query:

```
CONSTRUCT 
WHERE { <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator> ?predicate ?object }
```

Comment: @BrentLobbezoo glad to help. By the way, since your SO account is rather new you might now be aware of this, but: rather than thanking people in a comment, you should consider voting up or accepting answers that you've found helpful. See the section ["what should I do when someone answers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the help section.